# How to configure a JanusGraph image for running in docker

Tags: docker, janusgraph

I follow this installation guide : https://docs.janusgraph.org/getting-started/installation/

I run :

```
docker run -it -p 8182:8182 janusgraph/janusgraph
```

but when i try to connect with the gremlin console I have this exception :

```
gremlin-driver-initializer] INFO org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ConnectionPool - Signalled closing of connection pool on Host{address=localhost/127.0.0.1:8182, hostUri=ws://localhost:8182/gremlin} with core size of 2
18:32:42.556 [gremlin-driver-initializer] ERROR org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Client - Could not initialize client for Host{address=localhost/127.0.0.1:8182, hostUri=ws://localhost:8182/gremlin}
18:32:42.560 [main] ERROR org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Client -
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information*
```

I try with docker desktop and realize than my container automatically stop after 26 seconds. I have read than docker container automatically stop when nothing run on it. When I inspect it there is the message :

```
/etc/opt/janusgraph/janusgraph-server.yaml will be used to start JanusGraph Server in foreground.
```

Could you help me to configure it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help, HadoopMarc, but it wasn't a issue of different console version, i try to call:

```
docker inspect <container-id>
```

and I discover that :

```
"State": {
    "Status": "exited",
    "Running": false,
    "Paused": false,
    "Restarting": false,
    "OOMKilled": true,
    "Dead": false,
    "Pid": 0,
    "ExitCode": 137,
    "Error": "",
    "StartedAt": "2022-11-22T08:18:16.4661912Z",
    "FinishedAt": "2022-11-22T08:19:21.7929991Z"
},
```

with "OOMKilled": true. I affect more RAM to my docker container ( swith from 1Go to 20 Go and my docker container successfully started ! :)

But still with no logs .. :(

Answer (score 0):

When you start the container with janusgraph server like you did, it should proceed with log messages until:

```
6028 [gremlin-server-boss-1] INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer  - Gremlin Server configured with worker thread pool of 1, gremlin pool of 8 and boss thread pool of 1.
6028 [gremlin-server-boss-1] INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer  - Channel started at port 8182.
```

It then keeps running in a waiting loop for clients to connect.

When connecting from a local gremlin console with the same TinkerPop version as logged by the janusgraph container, connecting should proceed as follows:

```
plugin activated: janusgraph.imports
gremlin> :remote connect tinkerpop.server conf/remote.yaml
==>Configured localhost/127.0.0.1:8182
gremlin> :remote console
==>All scripts will now be sent to Gremlin Server - [localhost/127.0.0.1:8182] - type ':remote console' to return to local mode
gremlin> g.V()
gremlin> g.addV()
==>v[4264]
```

Comment: When I start my container the only log I have is  : "/etc/opt/janusgraph/janusgraph-server.yaml will be used to start JanusGraph Server in foreground". How can I see the logs ?

Comment: You say I have to connect with the same version, how can I check the version of my server ?

Comment: When I ran the docker image earlier today it was JanusGraph Server 0.6.2 (latest) using TinkerPop 3.5.3. This was also in the logs. If you install JanusGraph locally it automatically has the right TinkerPop version.

Comment: I have tried to use another console version, it seem better but unfortunately still not working

Comment: Do the logs of the JanusGraph container proceed until "Channel started at port 8182."?

Comment: I have no logs ! how to acces to this logs ?

Comment: If you run the "docker run -it -p 8182:8182 janusgraph/janusgraph" statement in a shell, the janusgraph log output appears on stdout, this means as output in the shell.

Comment: You are right ! Previously,  I had only one message : "/etc/opt/janusgraph/janusgraph-server.yaml will be used to start JanusGraph Server in foreground", but it was only because my server was short on memory just after that ! Thanks, now I can see my logs :)